# Create a post route that adds references to its relations

Tags: express, mongoose, mern

I've got the basic MERN Stack app running I can, GET, POST and Delete Topics and Post separately, they have relationship in Schema but I don't understand how to route it properly to incorporate the relations when POSTing.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

 const Post = require("../../models/Post");
 const Topic = require('../../models/Topic');

router.post("/", (req,res) => {
  //gets topic id from param
const {topic} = req.params;
  //creating a new post
const newPost = new Post({
    post: req.body.post,
    description: req.body.description,
    topic_id: req.body.topic_id
});
  //get topic by id
const topic_obj = Topic.findById(topic);
  //add posts to topic_object 
topic_obj.posts.push(newPost);
  //and save
topic_obj.save()
    .then(newPost.save()
    .then(post => res.json(post)).catch(err => console.log(err)));
});
module.exports = router;
```

I Don't know if you need more information 
I pushed it to GitHub for some helpL https://github.com/wolffles/bloccit-node/blob/react/routes/api/posts.js

Answer (score 0):

Accoarding to `TopicSchema`:

```
const TopicSchema = new Schema({
topic: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
posts: [
    { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'post'
    }
],
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}});
```

To incorporate relation between `Topic` and `Post` you need to add `_id` property of newly created `Post` object to `posts` field in `Topic` object that this newly created `Post` represents.

```
topic_obj.posts.push(newPost._id);
```

**EDIT:**
In your code there are some issues that an cause errors.

1. `const {topic} = req.params;` You should validate whether `topic` is a valid `ObjectId`
2. You should also validate request body and check if `description` and `post` has required format.
3. You dupicate `Topic` id by passing it in request body and also          asa request param.
4. `const topic_obj = Topic.findById(topic);` This is an *async* operation, it returns `Promise` not result of query.

Code should look like (*it is not tested*):

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const Post = require("../../models/Post");
const Topic = require("../../models/Topic");

router.post("/:topicId", async (req, res) => {
 const { topicId } = req.params;

 //TODO: validate if topic is a valid ObjectID
  const validTopicId = validateTopicId(topicId);
  if (!validTopicId) return res.status(400).send("Invalid param.");

   //TODO: validate req.body.description and req.body.post
   const validBody = validateBody(req.body);
   if (!validBody) return res.status(400).send("Invalid data.");

  const newPost = new Post({
   post: req.body.post,
   description: req.body.description,
   topic_id: topicId
 });

 const topic = await Topic.findById(topicId);
 if (!topic) return res.status(400).send("Invalid param.");

 topic.posts.push(newPost._id);

 await topic.save();
 await newPost.save();

 res.send();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: hmm not sure if thats correct, I tried on postman and im getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" so i console.log topic_obj and its undefined.

Comment: Check out edit. there are some issues in your code apart from `mongoose schemas`

Comment: This is a big problem, my server.js doesn't have posts using a topics/:id path. I'm going to have to come back to this, I need to learn much more about how to set up my server.js before i can finish this problem.